# ASP.NET Core Identity with JWT

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, jwt, asp.net-identity, bearer-token

**Problem**: I have implemented aspnet identity using JWT token authorisation I have followed all instructions which has been presented and for some reason I cannot get it to work and cannot see any issues in the code. I am sure I am missing something but still cannot see it after hours of research.
**Approach**: I have used a JWT token method and made it a http only cookie. You will note from the screenshot below that the cookie seems to generate correctly and can see it once the sign in occurts
**Issues**: However, the cookie does not seem to allow authorisation to the shows controller with this cookie. I tried items such as putting "Bearer " before the value in the cookie however this just ended up making the outcome worse with the value transforming to "Bearer%20< tokenkey >" which is not what the authorization would expect.

Any help or guidance here would be really appreciated as am really struggling to see the issue.

Code below for:

1. Program.cs - this is where the authentication and authorisation has been configured for JWT
2. Login Controller - this is where the user is being authenticated and then issued with a token
3. Shows Controller - this is the end point which is protected by the implemented authentication

````
    namespace Bhavik_WebAPIFreshQuickStart1
    {
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
                // Add services to the container.
    
                builder.Services.AddDbContext<TvshowDBContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
                );
    
    
                builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<TvshowDBContext>();
    
                builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
    
                        ValidIssuer = "BhavikCorp",
                        ValidAudience = "TestAudience",
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("PutSuperSecretKeyHere")),
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)
                    };
                });
    
                builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
    
                builder.Services.AddControllers();
                // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
                builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
                builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    
                var app = builder.Build();
    
                // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
                if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseSwagger();
                    app.UseSwaggerUI();
                }
    
                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    
                app.UseAuthentication();
                app.UseAuthorization();
    
    
                app.MapControllers();
    
                app.Run();
            }
        }
    }
    ```
    
    ```
     
    namespace WebAPIFreshQuickStart1.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
    
    
        public class LoginController : ControllerBase
        {
            private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
            private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
            private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    
            public LoginController(IConfiguration configuration, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
            {
                _signInManager = signInManager;
                _userManager = userManager;
                _configuration = configuration;
            }
    
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> LoginUser(LoginDto loginDto)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginDto.Email);
    
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, loginDto.Password, false, false);
    
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
    
    
                    SymmetricSecurityKey key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("PutSuperSecretKeyHere")); // Replace with your actual secret key
                    SigningCredentials creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    
    
                    JwtSecurityToken tokenGenerator = new JwtSecurityToken(
                        issuer: "BhavikCorp", // Replace with your issuer
                        audience: "TestAudience", // Replace with your audience  
                        claims: null,
                        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5), // Token expiration time
                        signingCredentials: creds
                         );
    
                    JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenresult = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                    string token = tokenresult.WriteToken(tokenGenerator);
                   
    
                    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("Authorization", token, new CookieOptions
                    {
                        HttpOnly = true,
                        Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(6)
                    });
    
                    return Ok(result);
                };
                return BadRequest(result);
    
            }
        }
    }
    ```
    
    '''
       namespace WebAPIFreshQuickStart1.Controllers
    {
        [Authorize]
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class ShowsController : ControllerBase
        {
            private readonly TvshowDBContext _context;
    
            public ShowsController(TvshowDBContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }
    
            // GET: api/Shows
            [HttpGet]
            public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Show>>> GetShows()
            {
              if (_context.Shows == null)
              {
                  return NotFound();
              }
                return await _context.Shows.ToListAsync();
            }
    }

'''
````

Comment: You have posted far too much code for us to look at. Please reduce it down to the absolute minimum needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Lets try a quick thing me and you , get the token and go try at post man, take the generated token and put it on postman and try to make a call, 
and yes try and put  ==> Append("Authorization", "Bearer " +token,

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada It did indeed work in postman, however I am not sure why the original HTTP context which is being sent is not placing the JWT token in that format to the client, i.e. Bearer <token>. How do I get it to send it in the correct manner so it comes back automatically from the client in the expected manner?

Comment: @Dai thanks, I have trimmed the code snippets provided to focus on the key elements, hope this shorter version helps

Comment: Don't use bearer auth in web applications: https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/asp-net-core-angular-xsrf-62c3833fd1fe

Comment: @Dai also when introducing "Append("Authorization", "Bearer " +token, " I get this output which is replacing the space with "%20".
Bearer%20eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2OTc2MjcyODcsImlzcyI6IkJoYXZpa0NvcnAiLCJhdWQiOiJUZXN0QXVkaWVuY2UifQ.FxczlHahbhT0o6qySQpui0hx6FGCyXLdMSiIgnq0_Kk